# I am not getting output filds when i am using ngFor with json object

Tags: angular

> HI, I am using below dummy json object:

```
[
  {
    "username": "ramu",
    "user_id": "222",
    "profileImage": "ramu.jpg",
    "status": "15",
    "address": [
      {
        "type": "permanent",
        "city": "mtm",
        "pin": "521001",
        "personal1": [
          {
            "age": "26",
            "color": "white"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "residential",
        "city": "chennai",
        "pin": "600024",
        "personal2": [
          {
            "age": "26",
            "color": "white"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

> and below i am using ngfor for getting iterating elements

```
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of profile.address">
    {{item.type}}
    </ion-item>
```

how get address type: permanent and personal age:26?

Comment: is `profile` the json object?

Comment: What do you mean by `get address type: permanent and personal age:26`?

Comment: yes, profile is an json object @suraj

Comment: so..it should `profile[0].address`?

Comment: yes suraj,and i need to get personal with age:26

Comment: Then, every object must contain `personal` property not `personal1` and `personal2` so on.

Comment: Hi SaiUnique, i am getting error below  Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays, kindly help me.

Comment: The only thing I can say is, your data is very very very complex. Just simplify your data to use it in **HTML** template

Comment: @RamuMothukuri, address is array only. First of all correct the object and then try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your data complexity I have used 3-loops in html template. It's better to simplify data, just a suggestion.

Here is working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Rx7EgTQjZQ6VC66hDmee?p=preview)

I just used `#something` in `*ngFor` because of version support. Just change it to `let something`

I just used `div`'s to show you to get data. You can use as your wish

Comment: I have used (<ion-item *ngFor="let user of profile">
). it's working fine.  I have check in my code, where is the mistake is i have declared profile as object (profile : {}) instead of creating profile array( profile : any[] = [];). After changing my object to array every thing working fine

Answer (score 1):

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of profile[0].address">
{{item.type}}
</ion-item>
```

Profile seems to be object of an array, so specify the index. If you have multiple profiles use two *ngFor statements, one for the profile, one for the address.

Comment: OK Sriram, Kindly tell me how to use multi for for profile and other address and last personal

Comment: It would be as simple as :

`<div *ngFor="let item of profile">
     <div *ngFor="let addr of item.address">
           {{addr.type}}
     </div>
 </div>`

This might have a simpler implementation, but according to me it will work fine. For getting the personal object information assign a common object or array and access them from within the repeaters.

Comment: Hi Sriram, I am getting below. Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Comment: If you want to traverse an Object which I think you are currently doing, use `in` instead of `of` in the *ngFor syntax.

Comment: HI Sriram, when i am using (in) showing error:Unhandled Promise rejection:

Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngForIn'

Comment: Can you put the entire profile object as you use it in your code? I think this might be because of the structure of the object or array that is accessed.

Comment: Hi Sriram, I have check in my code, where is the mistake is i have declared profile as object (profile : {}) instead of creating profile array( profile : any[] = [];). After changing my object to array every thing working fine. Great help Sriram